# how to download and install an APK file by an intent?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making my app to be updated via my own file server instead of Google Play-store. However, it does not work well. After confirming to "update", APK file is downloaded, it is not opened correctly. Please check the demonstration https://youtu.be/qDSGZ9fQ1Oo

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
    private fun checkUpdate(){
        val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            "https://myserver/release.json",
            null,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                if(response.getInt("version") > versionCode){
                    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert)
                    builder.setTitle("Update to v" + response.getString("version") + " ?")
                    builder.setMessage(response.getString("note"))

                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
                        downloadUpdate(response.getString("version"))
                    }

                    builder.setNegativeButton("No") { _, _ ->
                        showUserInteraction()
                    }

                    builder.setCancelable(false)

                    builder.show()
                }else{
                    showUserInteraction()
                }
            },
            Response.ErrorListener{ _ ->
                showUserInteraction()
            }
        )

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }

    private fun downloadUpdate(versionCode: String) {
        registerReceiver(onDownloadComplete(), IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))

        val request = DownloadManager
            .Request(Uri.parse("https://myserver/app-release.apk"))
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "myapp_v" + versionCode + ".apk")

        downloadManager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request)
    }

    private class onDownloadComplete: BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val c = downloadManager.query(DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId))
            if(c != null){
                c.moveToFirst()
                val fileUri = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI))
                val mFile = File(Uri.parse(fileUri).path!!)
                val fileName = mFile.absolutePath

                context.unregisterReceiver(this)

                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                var contentUri: Uri
                if (SDK_VER >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileProvider", File(fileName))
                }else{
                    contentUri = Uri.fromFile(File(fileName))
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                }

                intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
                startActivity(context, intent, null)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

May anyone please point out my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Which Android OS you're trying this ?

Comment: @MD I am trying on Android 9 on Samsung S10+

Comment: Do you have this permission in manifest.xml `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />` ?

Comment: @MD oh my god... I don't see any permission warning on the debugger... thankyou very much!

Comment: @y2kbug I had same issue in last week. Just one permission needed for Android >= 8.0

Comment: @pskink no idea, I have just copied it somewhere on the Internet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add below permission in your **manifest.xml** file.

If an app uses a **targetSdkLevel** of **26** or above and prompts the user to install other apps, the manifest file needs to include the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

You can see below link why it's needed

1. [Link1](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/making-it-safer-to-get-apps-on-android-o.html)
2. [Link2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INSTALL_PACKAGES)

Comment: Strange: dont need it with 8 and 9.

Comment: It's required for Android O that's what [official blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/making-it-safer-to-get-apps-on-android-o.html) said

Comment: But then: why can i do without?

Comment: Which targetSDK are you using ?

Comment: From Link1 `If an app uses a targetSdkLevel of 26 or above and prompts the user to install other apps, the manifest file needs to include the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission:`  I use 29.

Comment: Really strange for me. Let me ask to Android Community